# Update earliest row in group

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm attempting to construct an SQL statement for MySQL that will update a single row in a group. Taking the records below I need to update the IsPrimary flag so that the earliest record for each user is set to 1.

```
 ID       | UserID      | Inserted    | IsPrimary
----------|-------------|-------------|----------
000f83    | 79b8c3      | 2012-03-14  | 0
001401    | 79b8c3      | 2012-03-15  | 0
002e7d    | 4652a2      | 2012-02-22  | 0
003ca6    | 4652a2      | 2012-02-13  | 0
```

So the above records would end up as:

```
 ID       | UserID      | Inserted    | IsPrimary
----------|-------------|-------------|----------
000f83    | 79b8c3      | 2012-03-14  | 1
001401    | 79b8c3      | 2012-03-15  | 0
002e7d    | 4652a2      | 2012-02-22  | 0
003ca6    | 4652a2      | 2012-02-13  | 1
```

Comment: Is it possible that several rows in a group have the same date in `inserted`?

Comment: No. I've abbreviated it to a date for the question but in reality the field also has a time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give this a ry:

```
update t, (
  select t1.id anId from t t1
  left join t t2
  on t1.userId = t2.userId and t1.inserted > t2.inserted
  where t2.inserted is null
) s
set IsPrimary = 1
where t.id = anId
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9fe94/1).

Comment: It looks like that works for a case where there are only two records per user? I should have noted that there can be more than 2 in most cases.

Comment: @sipwiz Please, send me a fiddle with the data set up so that it doesn't work for more (it works with any amount:).

Comment: You're right. I did have some records with duplicate Inserted values but that's because they are test data, won't happen in production.

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
update t
set t.IsPrimary = 1
from myTable t
inner join myTable t2 on t.UserID = t2.UserID and t.Inserted<t2.Inserted
```

Comment: It would set isprimary in all rows in a group except of the last

Comment: i am assuming that there are two rows per user as in sample